# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' when trying to display a list of items

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a list of dates. I want to render it in a list of widgets but I'm getting an error: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'. Is there a better way to render a list of dates?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Basic List';

    var start = DateTime.now();
    var end = DateTime(2021, 12, 31);
    var list = [];

    while (start.isBefore(end)) {
        list.add(start);
        start = start.add(Duration(days: 1));
    }


    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: getDaysInWeek(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> getDaysInWeek() {
  var start = DateTime.now();
  var end = DateTime(2021, 12, 31);
  var list = [];
  while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    list.add(start);
    start = start.add(Duration(days: 1));
  }

  return list.toList();
}
```

Comment: DateTime isn't a subclass of Widget so you can return a list of DateTime when you want a List of Widget. Try doing list.add(Text(start.toString()) to make a list of Text Widgets that display the DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map your `List<DateTime` to `List<Widget`. Intuitively this is necessary because you cannot display `DateTime` in Flutter, you can only *display `Widget`s*!

This could look like this:

```dart
List<Widget> get daysInWeek {
  final end = DateTime(2021, 12, 31), list = <DateTime>[];
  DateTime start = DateTime.now();

  while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    list.add(start);
    start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
  }

  return list.map((DateTime time) {
    return Text(time.toString());
  }).toList();
}
```

---

You will notice two things:

1. I mapped the `DateTime` objects to `Text` objects and [`Text` is a widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html) that displays `String`s as text.
2. The syntax is a little different in a few places to be more idiomatic Dart code. I am sure you will intuitively understand this syntax.